# Compile-time Validated Type Erasure

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Here's my goal: to erase type information to simplify object access. Here's a simple example of my goal:

```
class magic;

magic m = std::string("hello"); // ok: m now stores a string
m = 32;                         // error: m is supposed to be a string
m += " world";                  // ok: operator for this exists
```

You might've noticed that this basically functions like the auto keyword.

To continue, it'd also preferably not vary its size depending on type (e.g. use a pointer). That way I can use a container for it.

```
std::vector<magic> vec; // homogeneous
vec.emplace_back(8);
vec.emplace_back(std::string("str"));
vec[0] = 4; // ok
vec[1] = 2; // no way, jose. compile error here because vec[1] is a string
```

The idea is that it has to be compile-time (not runtime like with std::any or std::variant) because the types are known at compile-time anyway; it's just extra overhead I don't need.

The reason I know this is possible is because auto already does the job. I just need a container of some type that functions like `auto*` that actually validates operations at compile-time to save on overhead and very tedious redundant programming.

Here's how I sort of plan to use it (warning: bad pseudo code)

```
struct base
{
    auto* p;
};
struct child: base<int> // child implements base as an int
{
    // use p and implement whatever functions are necessary
};
std::vector<base> vec;
vec.emplace_back(child());
vec[0] = 20;
```

If you prefer, pretend it's a map instead of a vector if you worry about the "key" access being changed depending on what's pushed-back. But I have a hunch that the stl containers aren't going to work anyway, so feel free to post an answer that is a container that uses compile-time type erasure as I think that might be much easier than an independent type.

Comment: Really sounds like you just want a variant. It'll almost certainly perform faster than this and be lower maintenance cost...

Comment: @GManNickG that's run-time though :(

Comment: use `tuple` and `tuple_cat` instead of `emplace_back`?

Comment: Define runtime? You are already using std::vector in your examples, do you mean you want something like a compile-time vector with a compile-time variant?

Comment: @user3365922 Oh sounds like a good idea. Mind posting an example as an answer of what you have in mind? If it works like what I'd like I'll accept it.

Comment: You can’t guarantee at compile time that the type won’t change. Consider creating a `vector<magic> vec` containing a string, then inserting `argc` ints at the beginning. Then you try to access `vec[1]`. The compiler has no way of knowing what `argc` is at compile time, so cannot know if that’s an int or a string.

Comment: It seems there is a misunderstanding of what runtime and compile mean here. This question would be clearer if you asked about your requirements, rather than a specific proposed solution. In particular in "The reason I know this is possible is because auto already does the job." - all auto does is deduce a type, as if you typed something out yourself. It has very little to do with compile-time or runtime value guarantees.

Comment: @DanielH Pretend it's a map, then :)

Comment: @user3365922 unfortunately, there is no way to "reassign" a tuple type so it can't be a class member. it requires the type parameters ahead of time and it cant be deduced based on usage :/

Comment: You “know this is possible”?  `vector<auto*>` most certainly does not exist.

Comment: @DavisHerring You are correct, it does not exist. Why post a comment?

Comment: But if this existed as you describe, you *could* do a vector, which doesn’t work. You need to give up on some of your requirements.

Comment: @DanielH I know it doesn't exist as a keyword; but I know certainly that templates are powerful enough to actually implement this idea.

Comment: Templates aren't magic. They won't allow you to solve the issue Daniel H pointed out.

Comment: My solution would require pretty drastic rewrite of the above example so that everything is callback based, including assignment via out params. Might be worse than the existing problem, but I think this could work (writing code in godbolt).

Comment: @Mat like in my question, feel free to consider making your own custom compile-time container. it doesn't actually need to be a vector

Comment: @DavidLedger Cleaning it up is honestly not a problem for me. As long as the proof of concept is there, it can be done in a clean way I'm sure. And if not, it's not that big of a deal for me either.

Comment: Alright, I'll continue my attempt. Not completely sure the compiler will find the errors you need but I'll post my failed attempt worst case.

Answer (score 2):

Type erasure is a runtime concept. By definition, it cannot be validated at compile-time. If any such `magic` type could exist, there is no way that it could determine *at compile-time* that `vec[0] = 4` is OK, while `vec[1] = 2` isn't.

> The reason I know this is possible is because auto already does the job.

No, it does not. `auto` is a grammatical construct that causes C++ to deduce the (compile-time determined) type of the variable based on the (compile-time determined) type of an expression. `auto` exists within the compiler, not the runtime.

What you want is something that happens at runtime. While the type of any particular `vec[X]` is determined at compile-time, the *value* of it is a runtime property. You want the value to somehow make an assignment a compile error or not. That is not possible.

This is why `tuple` uses `get<X>` rather than `get(X)`. The index *must* be a compile-time constant, which allows the type of `get<X>` to potentially be different for each particular `X` in a tuple.

The properties of a type, like being assignable from an integer, are *compile-time* constructs. That is, either `vec[X] = 4` is well-formed code or it isn't; it is impossible to make it *sometimes* be well-formed and sometimes not be, depending on `X` and the contents of the `vec`. You can make it UB, or throw an exception. But you can't make it a *compile error*.

Comment: Okay, then pretend it's `custom_container.get< 3 >( )` or something with a key instead.

Comment: @nowi: But you already have a container like that; it's called "tuple". Of course, you can't insert or remove anything from it, because that would be a runtime process and its compile-time characteristics have to be determined at... compile-time.

Comment: With `consteval`, you **can** make some such things be ill-formed based on function arguments—but you can’t make their *type* depend on them.

Comment: @DavisHerring: "*you can make some such things be ill-formed based on function arguments*" That would require the values in question to be constant expressions. The OP isn't asking for that.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That’s true (since it’s supposed to be the `=` and not the `[X]` that’s ill-formed); I was just speaking to the “impossible to make it [] well-formed [] depending on `X`”, since that’s not (*always*) true anymore.

Comment: @DavisHerring: "*I was just speaking to the “impossible to make it [] well-formed [] depending on X”, since that’s not (always) true anymore.*" But the "it" in question was the most recent code I was talking about, which included the `=` operation.

Comment: @NicolBolas: But it also included the call to `operator[]`.  (I’m not saying this matters to your purposes here!)

Comment: I will reask the question more specifically.

Comment: "This is why tuple uses get<X> rather than get(X). The index must be a compile-time constant, which allows the type of get<X> to potentially be different for each particular X in a tuple."
std::get has a type overload, std::get<int>(t) is valid.

Comment: @DavidLedger: I don't know how that's relevant. I didn't say that this wasn't true. And not passing a value means that `get` doesn't work. So I don't know what this matters to anything that was said in what you quoted. In particular, note the phrase "in a tuple"; that implies that you have passed a tuple.

Comment: This: https://godbolt.org/z/Prqzp7, you said "The index must be a compile-time constant". Its fine for index to now be known if the type is known. Just a moment, you can also not know the type.

Comment: @DavidLedger: I was not talking about some hypothetical version of `get` that returns a `void*`; I was talking about a `get` that does what `std::get` actually does and therefore has to take a compile-time constant index.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I didn't realize you were talking exclusively about std::get and not using it as broadly applied reasoning for why you cannot do certain things at compile time. This is a version with no compile time types or indexes which also returns a valid type (kind of...).
https://godbolt.org/z/7qMiEp My point is only that the problem can be transformed many ways. It doesn't sound to me that the poster requires the same syntax he posted as an example.

Comment: i dont think type erasure has to be runtime. i mean as long as you distinguish between compile and runtime. type erasure at compile time makes a lot of sense, its basically rust traits, and its something that c++ misses. think of a template function that at the interface says: I take a anything that has foo and bar as members, unforutnately there is no mechanismto "erase" the rest of the input type and makre sure only foo and bar are used.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot answer you question with the same syntax as in the question. Because as stated by others `auto` works differently to your assumption. `auto` is just a deduced type.

If it is assigned an `int` the type of the `auto` is `int`. However, this only applies when the type of auto is deduced. Any proceeding assignment is just assigning to an `int`, not to an `auto`. The type of `auto` is not dynamic and its storage is also not dynamic, this is why auto cannot be used to store various different types in a `std::vector`.

Just to add to the other answer, hopefully helping understanding:

---

```
auto i = 10;
```

The type of `i` here is `int` not `auto`.

---

```
auto b = true;
```

The type of `i` here is `bool` not `auto`.

---

However, I can do my best to solve what I believe is the problem your facing.

---

**What this answer does:**

1. At compile time ensure that access to a variable is done through a function with correct parameter type (bypassing the need for checking type).
2. Provide access to type erased data without exceptions (I think its safe...).
3. Allow modification of the data.

---

**What this doesn't do:**

1. Run at compile time, due to reinterpret case.
2. Allow assignment directly through members in std::vector<>, although you can assign from within the called access function.

---

**How it works:**

A callback function with a typed parameter of T& is type erased and stored as a generic function. The storage for this function is void (*)() because function pointers are not the same as normal void * pointers, they often have different sizes.

The **accessor** function with the typed parameter is setup to be called by a function with two type erased pointer parameters. The parameters are converted to their real types within this function, the types are known because they were present on the constructor of the **base** object. A pointer to the function created within the constructor as a lambda is stored in the **runner** function pointer.

When the function **access** is run, the **runner** function with parameters **data** and the **acessor** function. Once the runner function is executed it internally executes the **accessor** function with the parameter **data** but this time after it is cast to the correct type.

When access is required a type erased version of the above function is called which internally calls the typed function. I can add support for lambdas in a later version of this but its pretty complicated already and I thought I would just post now...

Inside the base class a **destructor** class exists. This is a general way to store a type erased destructor, is almost the same as [Herb Sutters method](https://herbsutter.com/2016/09/25/to-store-a-destructor/). This just makes sure that data given to the base has its destructor run.

---

A heap based approach is simpler conceptually you can run it here : 
https://godbolt.org/z/cb-a6m

A stack based approach is maybe faster by has more limitations :
https://godbolt.org/z/vxS4tJ

---

**The code heap based (simplier) code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


template <typename T>
struct mirror { using type = T; };
template <typename T>
using mirror_t = typename mirror<T>::type;

struct destructor
{
    const void* p = nullptr;
    void(*destroy)(const void*) = nullptr;
    //
    template <typename T>
    destructor(T& data) noexcept :
        p{ std::addressof(data) },
        destroy{ [](const void* v) { static_cast<T const*>(v)->~T(); } }
    {}
    destructor(destructor&& d) noexcept
    {
        p = d.p;
        destroy = d.destroy;
        d.p = nullptr;
        d.destroy = nullptr;
    }
    destructor& operator=(destructor&& d) noexcept
    {
        p = d.p;
        destroy = d.destroy;
        d.p = nullptr;
        d.destroy = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    //
    destructor() = default;
    ~destructor()
    {
        if (p and destroy) destroy(p);
    }
};

struct base
{
    using void_ptr_t = void*;          // Correct size for a data pointer.
    using void_func_ptr_t = void(*)(); // Correct size for a function pointer.
    using callback_t = void (*)(void_func_ptr_t, void_ptr_t);
    //
    void_ptr_t data;
    void_func_ptr_t function;
    callback_t runner;
    destructor destruct;
    //
    template <typename T>
    constexpr base(T * value, void (*callback)(mirror_t<T>&)) noexcept :
        data{ static_cast<void_ptr_t>(value) },
        function{ reinterpret_cast<void_func_ptr_t>(callback) },
        runner{
            [](void_func_ptr_t f, void_ptr_t p) noexcept
            {
                using param = T&;
                using f_ptr = void (*)(param);
                reinterpret_cast<f_ptr>(f)(*static_cast<T*>(p));
            }
        },
        destruct{ *value }
    {}
    //
    constexpr void access() const noexcept
    {
        if (function and data) runner(function, data);
    }
};

struct custom_type
{
    custom_type()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "\n";
    }
    custom_type(custom_type const&)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "\n";
    }
    custom_type(custom_type &&)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "\n";
    }
    ~custom_type()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << "\n";
    }
};
//
void int_access(int & a)
{
    std::cout << "int_access a = " << a << "\n";
    a = 11;
}
void string_access(std::string & a)
{
    std::cout << "string_access a = " << a << "\n";
    a = "I'm no longer a large string";
}
void custom_access(custom_type& a)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<base> items;
    items.emplace_back(new std::string{ "hello this is a long string which doesn't just sit in small string optimisations, this needs to be tested in a tight loop to confirm no memory leaks are occuring." }, &string_access);
    items.emplace_back(new custom_type{},   &custom_access);
    items.emplace_back(new int (10),        &int_access);
    //
    for (auto& item : items)
    {
        item.access();
    }
    for (auto& item : items)
    {
        item.access();
    }
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would cause `items[2].access(some_int)` to compile, while `items[0].access(some_int)` to fail to compile.

Comment: This requires a different access pattern, but achieves compile time validation of access with respect to types. Your example is also not correct, it should be `items[0].access()` with no parameters.

The error would have been picked up here: ``base(new int(10), &typed_access);`` on the construction of the base object.

The access function MUST be the in same place as the assigned variable because this is the only place the type of T exists (enabling checking of access function parameter types).

Comment: @DavidLedger: "*The error would have been picked up here*" But that's the initial creation of the value, not the *assignment* of the value. The OP's question was very clear on wanting to have a live object of the type and then assign to it, with the assignment failing at compile-time based on a property of the value currently in that object.

Comment: This answer is just a very round-about array of std::function's partially applied with a value. This has a relatively large runtime cost, in fact, and doesn't seem to solve any problem, as Nicol has been pointing out. The fact OP accepted this shows they really didn't have a well-formulated question to begin with.

Comment: After investigating this further, it doesn't seem to actually achieve my goal. It just validates that the function signature matches the type at assignment, then erases the type for access later. This seems like it can be extended in theory if I think hard enough but I also can't think of anything for this to make it work.

Comment: Its nothing like std::function. Its far more restricted  and it doesn't support function objects. The overhead is less than std::function, there is more locality of data and only 1 buffer (no heap allocation like std::function). There is a good reason herb sutter doesn't recommend storing destructors in std::function.

@NicolBolas You can mutate in whatever way when you call access from within the callback, including a normal assignment.

Comment: The poster, I believe only wanted compile time validation of the accessed type. I do that by restricting access to only from within a specific function and checking that the specific function is correct.